# VBScript error problems: Expected End 800A03F6

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to make a vbs work, the idea is it will remotely install an msi, to a list of machines contained with a txt file.

I am getting multiple errors, the first is:

> wrong number of arguments or invalid property assignment: "WshShell.Exec" Line 27, Char 1

```
WshShell.Exec "%COMSPEC% /C COPY " & StrInstallFile & " \\" & strComputer _
  & "\C$\Windows\Temp", 0, TRUE
```

I seemd to have got round this with:

```
Set WshExec = WshShell.Exec......
```

then got:

> expected end of statement line 27 cahr 29

adding an `&`:

```
Set WshExec = WshShell.Exec & "%COMSPEC%.....
```

now gets me:

> expected end of statement line 27 char 110

which is the penultimate comma

```
Set WshExec = WshShell.Exec & "%COMSPEC% /C COPY" & StrInstallFile _
  & " \\" & strComputer & "\C$\Windows\Temp", 0, TRUE
```

so i am not sure what is wrong at this point, and whether changing the whole line to a set was the right thing to have done.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are mixing .Run and .Exec. The prototype for .Exec:

```
object.Exec(strCommand)
```

shows that you need someting like:

```
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("%COMSPEC% /C COPY " & StrInstallFile & " \" & strComputer & "\C$\Windows\Temp")
```

If you want .Run instead, try something like:

```
Dim iRet : iRet = WshShell.Run(strCommand, [intWindowStyle], [bWaitOnReturn]) 
Dim iRet : iRet = WshShell.Run("%comspec% ...", 0, True)
```

Comment: worked perfect thanks, below is the complete script incase its of any use. I still have to add in some error checking, so I can check whether the msi completed.

Answer (score 0):

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("MachineList.Txt", 1)
StrInstallFile="install_flash_player_11_active_x.msi"
StrNoUpdateFile="mms.cfg"
StrInstallCMD="msiexec.exe /qn /i "

Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream

strComputer = objFile.ReadLine

' --------- Check If PC is on -------------
Set WshShell = WScript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set WshExec = WshShell.Exec("ping -n 1 -w 1000 " & strComputer) 'send 3 echo requests, waiting 2secs each
strPingResults = LCase(WshExec.StdOut.ReadAll)
If InStr(strPingResults, "reply from") Then

' ---------- Successful ping - run remote commands  ----------------

Set objWMIService = GetObject("winmgmts:" _
& "{impersonationLevel=impersonate}!\\" & strComputer & "\root\cimv2")


' --------- Copy msi to windows temp folder
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("%COMSPEC% /C COPY " & StrInstallFile & " \\" & strComputer & "\C$\Windows\Temp")

' --------- execute msi file on remote machine
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("%COMSPEC% /C psexec  \\" & StrComputer & " " & strInstallCMD & "c:\Windows\Temp\" & StrInstallFile)

' --------- Copy no "no update" file to remote machine, first line is for win7, second for xp
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("%COMSPEC% /C COPY " & StrNoUpdateFile & " \\" & strComputer & "\C$\Windows\SysWOW64\Macromed\Flash")
Set oExec = WshShell.Exec("%COMSPEC% /C COPY " & StrNoUpdateFile & " \\" & strComputer & "\C$\Windows\system32\macromed\flash")

Else

' ---------- Unsuccessful ping - Leave computer name in MachineList.txt and continue ----------------

strNewContents = strNewContents & strComputer & vbCrLf

End If
Loop

objFile.Close

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("MachineList.txt", 2)
objFile.Write strNewContents
objFile.Close
```

Comment: Well, it looks like you have copied this code from [here](http://www.itsupportguides.com/vbs-scripts/vbs-script-to-install-software-remotely/).